# How do I change Win10 display name? (network account)

Tags: windows-10, networking, user-accounts, user-profiles, profile

I'm trying to change my display name in windows 10, but because it's a network user account I'm not sure how to go about doing this. When I go into [ Settings > Accounts > Your Info ], I can see the current incorrect display name, correct username (in NETWORK\USER format), and that it correctly shows I'm an Administrator. I'm able to change my picture for the account but there is no option to change the display-name.

Maybe someone already asked/solved this, but I could only find posts about earlier versions of windows or server editions which don't seem to apply. If someone can definitively tell me it's impossible to do this from my workstation, and that I need to edit the user on the server instead, that would answer my question, although I'm hoping I can do this locally.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "Display Name"?  Are you talking about the username itself or something else?  Please edit your question to provide this additional clarification.

Comment: Is this a business computer? Having to install ADUC indicates to me that it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit win+r and type netplwiz. Now in the dialog select your username and click Properties. Now change your username and save settings and reboot.

It will not change your user profile name. Either boot into safe mode or a live Linux bootable USB flash drive and rename the userprofile.

Comment: Went through all the trouble of installing ADUC and found the object in the console to edit, but unfortunately it appears I do not have sufficient permissions to save changes... I think this is as far as I can get for now, unless you know any tricks for giving myself permission to edit the user account on the server, but definitely appreciate the help in finding where the setting was located - I'll get with my network admin some time during the week to see if they're able to change it from their end.

Comment: @Ash243x - Even if there were tricks, we would be unable to share them, since you are not a privileged user on your domain.  Have your network Administrator make the desired change.

Comment: Definitely understand but figured it was worth a shot to ask 
cheers

Answer (score 0):

For reference to others with the same question, I was able to access these settings from console (Start>Run>mmc), adding ADUC (File>add/remove snap-in>Active Directory Users and Computers), expanding ADUC, expanding the domain, opening 'users', and selecting the user from the list to edit. (assuming you have server permissions)

*ADUC might need to be installed, which I was able to get using instructions from here: https://theitbros.com/installing-active-directory-snap-in-on-windows-10/